# how to combine the tags with the same name and then rename the tag inside it in java?

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML file like this in a String variable

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <customer>
       <partyId>1000010700</partyId>
       <CustomerAccount>
          <accountType>2</accountType>
          <companyCode>6001</companyCode>
          <circleId>MU</circleId>
          <accountID>400000005901</accountID>
          <subscriptionType>1</subscriptionType>
       </CustomerAccount>
       <CustomerAccount>
          <accountType>1</accountType>
          <companyCode>6000</companyCode>
          <circleId>MU</circleId>
          <accountID>100000011972</accountID>
          <subscriptionType>1</subscriptionType>
          <Identifier>
             <value>7021137076</value>
          </Identifier>
       </CustomerAccount>
       <emailId>sonia.mathew@ril.com</emailId>
       <telephoneNumber>+917376452847</telephoneNumber>
       <name>
          <salutation>0002</salutation>
          <firstName>raghu</firstName>
          <middleName />
          <lastName>sanity</lastName>
       </name>
       <Product>
          <id>P10016</id>
          <name>VOLTE-VVM-DATA</name>
          <contractRefNumber />
          <productStatus>Z020</productStatus>
          <alias />
          <productStatusDescription />
          <activationDate>2016-02-18 10:09:09.0</activationDate>
          <Identifier>
             <name>MSISDN</name>
             <type />
             <value>7021137076</value>
             <subCategory>2</subCategory>
             <category>4</category>
          </Identifier>
          <ProductRelationship>
             <specificationId />
             <Identifier>
                <name>MSISDN</name>
                <type />
                <value>7021137076</value>
                <subCategory>2</subCategory>
                <category>4</category>
             </Identifier>
          </ProductRelationship>
          <Service>
             <name>VOICE VIDEO MESSAGING.</name>
             <Identifier>
                <name>MSISDN</name>
                <value>917021137076</value>
                <subCategory>3</subCategory>
                <category>2</category>
             </Identifier>
             <id>S40001</id>
             <PlanSpecification />
             <ServiceSpecification>
                <serviceType>Z0003</serviceType>
             </ServiceSpecification>
          </Service>
          <Service>
             <name>VOLTE-DATA</name>
             <Identifier>
                <name>IMSI</name>
                <value>405874888888172</value>
                <subCategory>3</subCategory>
                <category>2</category>
             </Identifier>
             <id>S40002</id>
             <PlanSpecification />
             <ServiceSpecification>
                <serviceType>Z0002</serviceType>
             </ServiceSpecification>
          </Service>
          <BusinessInteractionType>
             <name>CUGGRPDL</name>
          </BusinessInteractionType>
          <BusinessInteractionType>
             <name>CUGADMEM</name>
          </BusinessInteractionType>
          <BusinessInteractionType>
             <name>MSISDNCH</name>
          </BusinessInteractionType>
          <BusinessInteractionType>
             <name>FFMODIFY</name>
          </BusinessInteractionType>
          <BusinessInteractionType>
             <name>FFDELETN</name>
          </BusinessInteractionType>
          <BusinessInteractionType>
             <name>CUGGRPCR</name>
          </BusinessInteractionType>
          <BusinessInteractionType>
             <name>CUGDLMEM</name>
          </BusinessInteractionType>
          <BusinessInteractionType>
             <name>FFCREATE</name>
          </BusinessInteractionType>
          <BusinessInteractionType>
             <name>SIMCHNGE</name>
          </BusinessInteractionType>
          <BusinessInteractionType>
             <name>SSUSPEND</name>
          </BusinessInteractionType>
          <BusinessInteractionType>
             <name>RMSRVFTR</name>
          </BusinessInteractionType>
          <BusinessInteractionType>
             <name>SRVCEASE</name>
          </BusinessInteractionType>
          <BusinessInteractionType>
             <name>ADSRVFTR</name>
          </BusinessInteractionType>
          <BusinessInteractionType>
             <name>OGBARING</name>
          </BusinessInteractionType>
          <BusinessInteractionType>
             <name>DNDSERVC</name>
          </BusinessInteractionType>
          <ProductOffering>
             <id>OC4508</id>
             <name>VOLTE REGULAR OFFER</name>
          </ProductOffering>
          <customerAccount>
             <accountID>100000011972</accountID>
          </customerAccount>
          <billingType>1</billingType>
          <type>1</type>
       </Product>
       <preferredCommunicationChannel>INT</preferredCommunicationChannel>
       <preferredLanguage>EN</preferredLanguage>
       <segment>
  <attributeName>CUSTOMER_CATEGORY</attributeName>
      <attributeValue>0001</attributeValue>
       </segment>
    </customer>
```

---

### ********** Now I want to make business transaction tag into action tag and its data like this and also I want to change the name tag that is under customer tag and not the other to personal details tag

```
<actions>
    <element>NMBTRNFO</element>
    <element>CUGADMEM</element>
    <element>MOBTRNFR</element>
    <element>NMBTRNFR</element>
    <element>MSISDNCH</element>
    <element>CUGGRPCR</element>
    <element>CUGGRPDL</element>
    <element>SSUSPEND</element>
    <element>SRVCEASE</element>
    <element>CUGDLMEM</element>
    <element>FFDELETN</element>
    <element>RMSRVFTR</element>
    <element>FFMODIFY</element>
    <element>FFCREATE</element>
    <element>ASSOUSER</element>
    <element>ADSRVFTR</element>
    <element>DNDSERVC</element>
    <element>DISOUSER</element>
 </actions>
```

=============================================

I have been passing the XML as String to my servlet

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public test() {
    super();
}
protected Node getNode(String tagName, NodeList nodes) {
    for ( int x = 0; x < nodes.getLength(); x++ ) {
        Node node = nodes.item(x);
        if (node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)) {
            return node;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

protected String getNodeValue( Node node ) {
    NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int x = 0; x < childNodes.getLength(); x++ ) {
        Node data = childNodes.item(x);
        if ( data.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE )
            return data.getNodeValue();
    }
    return "";
}

protected String getNodeValue(String tagName, NodeList nodes ) {
    for ( int x = 0; x < nodes.getLength(); x++ ) {
        Node node = nodes.item(x);
        if (node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)) {
            NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
            for (int y = 0; y < childNodes.getLength(); y++ ) {
                Node data = childNodes.item(y);
                if ( data.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE )
                    return data.getNodeValue();
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}

protected String getNodeAttr(String attrName, Node node ) {
    NamedNodeMap attrs = node.getAttributes();
    for (int y = 0; y < attrs.getLength(); y++ ) {
        Node attr = attrs.item(y);
        if (attr.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(attrName)) {
            return attr.getNodeValue();
        }
    }
    return "";
}

protected String getNodeAttr(String tagName, String attrName, NodeList nodes ) {
    for ( int x = 0; x < nodes.getLength(); x++ ) {
        Node node = nodes.item(x);
        if (node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)) {
            NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
            for (int y = 0; y < childNodes.getLength(); y++ ) {
                Node data = childNodes.item(y);
                if ( data.getNodeType() == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE ) {
                    if ( data.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(attrName) )
                        return data.getNodeValue();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return "";
}
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
```

/*  protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

```
    System.out.println("*************************************");
    System.out.println(response.toString());
    //System.out.println(inp.toString());
    System.out.println(request.toString());

}*/

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
//  doGet(request, response);

    try {
        ArrayList<Object> al= new ArrayList<>();
        String req=request.getParameter("Text1");

        DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(req));
        Document doc = db.parse(is);

        NodeList   nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("partyId");

        for (int i=0; i < nodes.getLength();)
        {
           doc.renameNode(nodes.item(i), "", "customerId");
        }

        nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Product");

        for (int i=0; i < nodes.getLength();)
        {
           doc.renameNode(nodes.item(i), "", "products");
        }

        nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("CustomerAccount");

        for (int i=0; i < nodes.getLength();)
        {
           doc.renameNode(nodes.item(i), "", "accounts");
        }

        nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("telephoneNumber");

        for (int i=0; i < nodes.getLength();)
        {
           doc.renameNode(nodes.item(i), "", "mobileNumber");
        }

        nodes= doc.getElementsByTagName("customer");

        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

        Element contDet = doc.createElement("contactDetails");
        nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("mobileNumber");
        contDet.appendChild(nodes.item(0));
        nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("emailId");
        contDet.appendChild(nodes.item(0));
        root.appendChild(contDet);

        nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("ProductRelationship");

        for (int i=0; i < nodes.getLength();)
        {
           doc.renameNode(nodes.item(i), "", "dependancyInfo");
        }

        nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("BusinessInteractionType");

        for (int i=0; i < nodes.getLength();)
        {
           doc.renameNode(nodes.item(i), "", "actions");
        }

        nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Service");

        for (int i=0; i < nodes.getLength();)
        {
           doc.renameNode(nodes.item(i), "", "customerFacingServices");
        }

        nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("customerAccount");

        for (int i=0; i < nodes.getLength();)
        {
           doc.renameNode(nodes.item(i), "", "accountIds");
        }

        NodeList ndListFirstFile = doc.getElementsByTagName("actions");
        for (int i=0; i < nodes.getLength();)
        {
        Node nodeArea = doc.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0);
        ndListFirstFile.item(0).appendChild(nodeArea);
        }

        //Renaming name of action to element

        NodeList root12 = doc.getChildNodes();

        Node comp = getNode("customer", root12);
        Node exec = getNode("products", comp.getChildNodes() );

        NodeList nodes32 = exec.getChildNodes();

        nodes32=doc.getElementsByTagName("actions");
        for ( int x = 0; x < nodes32.getLength(); x++ ) {
        Node node = nodes32.item(x);
        System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
        if (node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("actions")) {
            NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
            for (int y = 0; y < childNodes.getLength(); y++ ) {
             //   Node data = childNodes.;
              Node abc= doc.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0);
                //Node data= abc.getNextSibling();

              //if(abc.hasChildNodes())
                   doc.renameNode(abc, "", "element");
                    // System.out.println( data.getNodeValue());
            }
        }
    }

        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
        System.out.println(xmlString);

        System.out.println(doc.toString());

        Element element = (Element)nodes.item(0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about to use xslt processing?

Comment: i have to give the code in java...now other things i dont know

Comment: Please, show us what you have tried. Provide us with a minimal, complete and verifiable example [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: added my servlet above

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code, but it's only for your task:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException,
                                              TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    f.setValidating(false);
    DocumentBuilder builder = f.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("utf-8"))));        
    Node root = doc.getFirstChild();        
    NodeList rootChilds = root.getChildNodes();
    Node product = null;
    // Searching "name" and "Product" tags
    for (int i = 0, j = rootChilds.getLength(); i < j; i++) {
        Node item = rootChilds.item(i);
        if ("name".equals(item.getNodeName())) {
            doc.renameNode(item, item.getNamespaceURI(), "PersonalDetails");
        }
        if ("Product".equals(item.getNodeName())) {
            product = item;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Creating "actions" tag
    Node actions = doc.createElement("actions");        
    product.appendChild(actions);

    // Removing "BusinessInteractionType" tag and copy its value to "element" tag
    for (int i = 0, j = product.getChildNodes().getLength(); i < j; i++) {
        Node item = product.getChildNodes().item(i);
        if (item != null && "BusinessInteractionType".equals(item.getNodeName())) {
            String value = item.getFirstChild().getNextSibling().getTextContent();
            Element element = doc.createElement("element");
            element.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value));            
            actions.appendChild(element);
            product.removeChild(item);                    
            --i;
        }            
    }        
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);    
    StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
    transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
    System.out.println(streamResult.getWriter().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to transform XML elements into different XML elements, you want to use [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt):

```
static void extractBusinessActions(String xml,
                                   Result result)
throws TransformerException {
    String xslt =
        "<?xml version='1.0'?>\n" +
        "<xsl:stylesheet" +
            " xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'" +
            " version='1.0'>\n" +
        "  <xsl:template match='//Product'>\n" +
        "    <actions>\n" +
        "      <xsl:for-each select='BusinessInteractionType/name'>\n" +
        "        <element><xsl:value-of select='.'/></element>\n" +
        "      </xsl:for-each>\n" +
        "    </actions>\n" +
        "  </xsl:template>\n" +
        "  <xsl:template match='text()|@*'/>\n" +
        "</xsl:stylesheet>\n";

    Transformer transformer =
        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(
            new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslt)));
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

    transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)), result);
}
```